# Avoid code repetition when implementing interfaces

Tags: c#, interface

I encounter myself in the following situation:

```
public interface IKitchenObjectParent
{
    public void DoParentStuff();
}
```

There are some major implementations of this interface that keeps repeating themselves in the code. I want to avoid that code repetition, here is an abstraction of my code:

```
public class Player: IKitchenObjectParent
{
    public void DoParentStuff()
    {
        // IMPLEMENTATION A
    }
}

public class BaseCounter
{
    // BaseCounter stuff
}

public class CuttingCounter : BaseCounter, IKitchenObjectParent
{
    public void DoParentStuff()
    {
        // IMPLEMENTATION A
    }
}

public class DeliveryCounter : BaseCounter, IKitchenObjectParent
{
    public void DoParentStuff()
    {
        // IMPLEMENTATION B
    }
}
```

I want to avoid the code repetition of implementation A, I thought at creating a class with `implementationA` and everyone that uses that implementation would extend it, but I don't think it is a good idea because of the `CuttingCounter` and `DeliveryCounter` classes, since I would have to make the `BaseCounter` class extend that new class, creating unnecessary inheritances, as the `BaseCounter` is not meant to be a `KitchenObjectParent` and there are other children of that class that also don't.

I also thought to create that same class with the implementation A, but as a child of `BaseCounter`, but in that way I would not be capable of using that implementation in the `Player` class not solving the code repetition problem.

What can I do about it?

Comment: Well, you could extract a class with implementation A and delegate to it. But whether this is a sound choice depends on additional context, especially how the interface is used.

Comment: From a certain perspective, this could be a Car, Bus and Airplane implementing IEngine interface. The solution may be that all of them have an IEngine. But it may also be different. Maybe the IEngine should be a different concept. One needs to understand the larger perspective to evaluate OO design.

Comment: Sounds like a case for aggregation instead of inheritance, but as stated in the prior comment, "it depends on additional context".

Comment: use default implementation in interfaces https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/

Comment: @Zdeněk Jelínek I was thinking about that. Basically what I have is an class that is linked to a parent and only one parent for certain informations such as position, rotation, etc. A parent in other hand might have how many of those KitchenObjects as it pleases. A parent only has to have a single method, OnChildAssignment, basically it is the method I call whenever a child is attached to that parent. One implementation is of a parent that can only hold a single object. The other one is of a parent that can hold multiple objects. I really don't know what I could change about it.

Comment: So taking the code you shared, I'd assume e.g. that Player and CuttingCounter both have multiple children and DeliveryCounter has just one child. So there is duplication between Player and CuttingCounter when it comes to managing the collection of children? If that's the case and the code is purely mechanical (as opposed to business logic), that may be quite fine, albeit I get that typing this out is unexciting. You could possibly wrap this into classes (e.g. ChildCollection) if there's more involved logic.

Comment: You could possibly do something like having a base class for everything with IChildrenContainer field that implements the common child management logic and supply CollectionChildrenContainer or SingleChildContainer from the derived types. This could also be done via a generic parameter. But there is coupling cost. It might also be possible to completely sidestep the problem and move the children management elsewhere, into a dedicated type. This is harder to extend and seems like a dependency magnet. But it feels tp me that the hierarchies you have shown are used for two distinct purposes.

Comment: @Zdeněk Jelínek, Thanks for the help. I will have a look at what I can do, I managed to get things working with little code repetition, it is not the best code, but it is good enough for now.

Comment: I would suggest considering moving the common logic simply into a separate class and injecting it via dependency injection instead of inheriting from it unless you strongly need inheritance for polymorphism in some place

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, assuming original code like

```cs
public interface IParent
{
    IEnumerable<object> Children { get; }
    void AddChild(object child);
    void RemoveChild(object child);
}

public class Player : IParent
{
    private readonly List<object> _children = new();

    public IEnumerable<object> Children => _children;

    public void AddChild(object child) => _children.Add(child);

    public void RemoveChild(object child) => _children.Remove(child);

    // Other methods
}

public class BaseCounter
{
    // Other methods
}

public class CuttingCounter : BaseCounter, IParent
{
    // Basically a duplication of Player here
    private readonly List<object> _children = new();

    public IEnumerable<object> Children => _children;

    public void AddChild(object child) => _children.Add(child);

    public void RemoveChild(object child) => _children.Remove(child);

    // Other methods
}

public class DeliveryCounter : BaseCounter, IParent
{
    private object? _child; // Note only single child

    public IEnumerable<object> Children => _child != null ? new[] { _child } : Enumerable.Empty<object>();

    public void AddChild(object child) => _child = child;

    public void RemoveChild(object child) => _child = null;

    // Other methods
}
```

As written, I don't see much point in removing the duplication - any such approach would lead to more code or tighter coupling.

However, should the implementation become more complex, there might be a case for elimination of the duplicity. Let's say that we want to avoid duplicating child in the list, overwriting single child or throwing when remove fails. Suddenly, all of the implementations need to be adapted in the same way. At this point, one approach would be to extract the logic into separate classes:

```cs
public class CollectionChildContainer
{
    private readonly HashSet<object> _children = new();

    public IEnumerable<object> Values => _children;

    public void Add(object child)
    {
        if (!_children.Add(child))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to add '{child}': It was already added.");
        }
    }

    public void Remove(object child)
    {
        if (!_children.Remove(child))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to remove '{child}': It was never added.");
        }
    }
}

public class Player : IParent
{
    private readonly CollectionChildContainer _children = new();

    public IEnumerable<object> Children => _children.Values;

    public void AddChild(object child) => _children.Add(child);

    public void RemoveChild(object child) => _children.Remove(child);

    // Other methods
}

public class CuttingCounter : BaseCounter, IParent
{
    private readonly CollectionChildContainer _children = new();

    public IEnumerable<object> Children => _children.Values;

    public void AddChild(object child) => _children.Add(child);

    public void RemoveChild(object child) => _children.Remove(child);

    // Other methods
}
```

With this approach, we have now introduced a concept of children container that allows us to change how the children are managed without changing the types that manage them. So the children management responsibility is moved elsewhere. In my opinion, this is good and probably as good as it gets with this design and language like C#.

Note that it makes assumption about child identity for comparisons. This may or may not be correct. I just put it in place to reflect how changing requirements for children management could cause significant amount of work if the code was duplicated.

One could say that this is still quite a bit of typing. We could create abstraction for children management and have distinct implementations and a base class for all children-managing types. This is trading off typing for coupling. Assuming that code is more expensive to understand and maintain than to type, this approach is often more expensive as a result. And it may not even be possible to do this if you need to inherit some framework class.

```cs
public interface IParent
{
    IEnumerable<object> Children { get; }
    void AddChild(object child);
    void RemoveChild(object child);
}

public interface IChildContainer
{
    IEnumerable<object> Values { get; }
    void Add(object child);
    void Remove(object child);
}

public class CollectionChildContainer : IChildContainer
{
    // As before
}

public class SingleChildContainer : IChildContainer
{
    private object? _child;

    public IEnumerable<object> Values => _child != null ? new[] { child } : Enumerable.Empty<object>();

    public void Add(object child)
    {
        if (_child != null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to add '{child}': Another child is already present.");
        }

        _child = child;
    }

    public void Remove(object child)
    {
        if (_child == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to remove '{child}': No child was set.");
        }
        else if (_child != child)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Failed to remove '{child}': The child to remove does not match child that is already set.");
        }
        else
        {
            _child = null;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Parent : IParent
{
    private readonly IChildContainer _children;

    public Parent(IChildContainer children) => _children = children;

    public IEnumerable<object> Children => _children.Values;

    public void AddChild(object child) => _children.Add(child);

    public void RemoveChild(object child) => _children.Remove(child);
}

public class Player : Parent
{
    public Player() : base(new CollectionChildContainer())
    {
    }

    // Other methods
}

public class BaseCounter : Parent
{
    public BaseCounter(IChildContainer children) : base(children)
    {
    }

    // Other methods
}

public class CuttingCounter : BaseCounter, IParent
{
    public CuttingCounter() : base(new CollectionChildContainer())
    {
    }

    // Other methods
}

public class DeliveryCounter : BaseCounter, IParent
{
    public DeliveryCounter() : base(new SingleChildContainer())
    {
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

With all that, it's still quite unclear what the children are for. There could be other approaches. Or the approach may not work at all if children need to be of specific type, especially if a `Player` would be restricted to specific type of children but this is a problem that goes all the way up to the `IParent` interface.